# How to effectively calculate an algorithm's time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

I'm studying algorithm's complexity and I'm still not able to determine the complexity of some algorithms ... Ok I'm able to figure out basic O(N) and O(N^2) loops but I'm having some difficult in routines like this one:

`// What is time complexity of fun()?
    int fun(int n)
    {
      int count = 0;
      for (int i = n; i > 0; i /= 2)
         for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            count += 1;
      return count;
    }`

Ok I know that some guys can calculate this with the eyes closed but **I would love to to see a "step" by "step" how to** if possible.

My first attempt to solve this would be to "simulate" an input and put the values in some sort of table, like below:

`for n = 100
Step   i
1      100
2      50
3      25
4      12
5      6
6      3
7      1`

Ok at this point I'm assuming that this loop is O(logn), but unfortunately as I said no one solve this problem "step" by "step" so in the end I have no clue at all of what was done ....

In case of the inner loop I can build some sort of table like below:

`for n = 100
Step   i      j
1      100    0..99
2      50     0..49
3      25     0..24
4      12     0..11
5      6      0..5
6      3      0..2
7      1      0..0`

I can see that both loops are decreasing and I suppose a formula can be derived based on data above ...

Could someone clarify this problem? (The Answer is O(n))

Comment: Simulating it can give you intuition, but the only way to get a definitive answer is to derive it analytically.

Comment: Yes I understand ... but how can I know step by step that this algorithm is O(n) ?

Comment: You've already count the number of operations. It's n + n/2 + n/4 + ... + 1. `n + n/2 + n/4 + ... + 1` <= `n * SUM(1 / 2^k), for k = [0,inf)` <= `n*2` ∈ `O(n)`

Comment: If you continually divide any number by `x`, you will get to 0 in `logx(n)` steps. So if you divide 1000 continually by 3, it'll take log-base-3(1000) steps to get to 0. And your inner loop does `n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + n/16 ...` iterations. That series has a limit of 2n. So your inner loop does at most 2n iterations, which makes it O(n).

Comment: Thanks @Dale, now I can understand the outer loop, If I perform some substitution it will become: 100 + 100/2 + 100/4 + 100/8 ... => 100 + 50 + 25 + 12 (very similar to my table). My doubt now is about the inner loop ... I learnt that I need to "multiply" the outer loop for the inner loop but In this case what is the derived formula for the inner loop? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another simple way to probably look at it is:

Your outer loop initializes i (can be considered step/iterator) at n and divides i by 2 after every iteration. Hence, it executes the i/2 statement log2(n) times. So, a way to think about it is, **your outer loop run log2(n) times**. Whenever you divide a number by a base continuously till it reaches 0, you effectively do this division log number of times. Hence, outer loop is O(log-base-2 n)

Your inner loop iterates j (now the iterator or the step) from 0 to i **every iteration of outer loop**. i takes the maximum value of n, hence the longest run that your inner loop will have will be from 0 to n. Thus, it is O(n).

Now, your program runs like this:

```
Run 1: i = n, j = 0->n
Run 2: i = n/2, j = 0->n/2
Run 3: i = n/4, j = 0->n/4
.
.
.
Run x: i = n/(2^(x-1)), j = 0->[n/(2^(x-1))]
```

Now, runnning time always "multiplies" for nested loops, so
O(log-base-2 n)*O(n) gives O(n) for your entire code

Answer (score 1):

Lets break this analysis up into a few steps.

First, **start with the inner for loop.**  It is straightforward to see that this takes exactly `i` steps.

Next, **think about which different values `i` will assume over the course of the algorithm**.  To start, consider the case where `n` is some power of 2.  In this case, `i` starts at `n`, then `n/2`, then `n/4`, etc., until it reaches `1`, and finally `0` and terminates.  Because the inner loop takes `i` steps each time, then the total number of steps of `fun(n)` in this case is exactly `n + n/2 + n/4 + ... + 1 = 2n - 1`.

Lastly, **convince yourself this generalizes to non-powers of 2**.  Given an input `n`, find smallest power of 2 greater than `n` and call it `m`.  Clearly, `n < m < 2n`, so `fun(n)` takes less than `2m - 1` steps which is less than `4n - 1`.  Thus `fun(n)` is `O(n)`.